# Because of Bnei Yisrael or Not

Tags: rashi, parashat-ki-tisa

Rashi (שמות לב:ז ד״ה ״לך רד), sourcing Brachot 32a, explains that HKB”H tells Moshe to descend from his greatness because H’ only gave Moshe greatness on account of bnei Yisrael.  In addition, Moshe was placed in נידוי by the בית דין של מעלה.

Further on in pasuk 10 chapter 32 H’ says ״...ואעשה אותך לגוי גדול״. But I thought Rashi said H’ only made Moshe great BECAUSE OF bnei Yisrael and punished Moshe by removing the greatness.  Yet the latter pasuk is says he need not worry about bnei Yisrael and that Moshe can continue serving H’ by allowing H’ to make him into a great nation and destroying bnei Yisrael.

The earlier pasuk said that H’ will only let Moshe be great on account of bnei Yisrael but later He says He is planning to make Moshe into a great nation regardless of it being on account of bnei Yisrael.

What is going on here with respect to Moshe’s greatness and H’ instructing him what to do with bnei Yisrael?